# Table of Contents Page column header always appears after the Acknowledgement entry in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm currently working on some changes in my dissertation. My school requires the Table of Contents page number column to have "Page" on top of it. My current `LaTeX` setup is as follows. In my main latex file, I have:

```
\begin{document}

% pretext pages
\DisplayTitlePage     % displays the title page with your provided         information
\DisplayCopyright     % displays the copyright page with your provided information:
                  % you don't need need to comment this line even if you don't have copyrighted material. Just commenting \setCopyright suffices.
\DisplaySignaturePage % displays the signature page with your provided information

\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Page}
\include{pretext/acknowledge}
\include{pretext/abstract}

% Table of contents, list of figures, list of tables
\setUpTables
```

The `\setUpTables` command is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\setUpTables}{
%\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Page}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{theTOC}
\tableofcontents \clearpage
\listoftables \clearpage
\listoffigures \clearpage
%\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{-2.5em}Chapter}
\addtocontents{lot}{\hspace{-1em}Table\hfill Page}
\addtocontents{lof}{\hspace{-1em}Figure\hfill Page}
}
```

Both acknowledgements and abstract are `\newenvironments`. This is what they look like:

```
\newenvironment{acknowledgments}{
\def\toclevel@section{0}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\def\toclevel@section{1}
\vspace*{2.0 \baselineskip}
\begin{center}\textbf{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}\end{center}
}{\newpage}

\newenvironment{abstract}{
\def\toclevel@section{0}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
\def\toclevel@section{1}
\vspace*{2.0 \baselineskip}
\begin{center}
  \MakeUppercase{STRUCTURAL PATTERN DISCOVERY IN DYNAMIC} \\
  \MakeUppercase{GRAPHS}\\
  Abstract \\
  \doublespace
  by \myname\\
  \singlespace
  \myschool \\
  \mydate \\
  \quadspace
\end{center}
  Chair: \mycommitteea, Ph.D.
\doublespace
}
{\newpage}
```

My problem is that the "Page" always appears after the first entry of the Table of Contents as shown in the image. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Table of contents]

**Update:** I've solved it in an extremely hacky manner. Basically I think some where either in the style file, or elsewhere the Acknowledgements is getting added to the TOC before the "Page". What I did was to comment out the

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}, and 
\addcontentsline{toc}{ABSTRACT}
```

and manually insert them after

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Page}
```

in the main `.tex` file

Other things that I will investigate is the differences between `\addcontentsline` and `\addtocontents` and if that has any bearing. Also try out `@barbarabeeton's` suggestion. Thanks for all the comments. `@ChristianHupfer` and `@Werner`, I will try to put in the MWE and entire `.sty` file after this madness is over. Thanks again!

Comment: `\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Page}` must be in place of `%\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{-2.5em}Chapter}`

Comment: You could try issuing a `\clearpage` after `\addtocontents{toc}{\hfill Page}`. Is your acknowledgement a regular `\chapter*`?

Comment: I suggest `\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{}{Page}}}` as the entry, but this does not solve the other issues

Comment: @Werner: Tried that but it didn't work. Acknowledgements is a \newenvironment.

Comment: @touhami: If I do that then the "Page" will appear not only after the Acknowledgements, but also after the Abstract, List of Figures, and List of Tables.

Comment: @user14269: Let's avoid speculating here... could you please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: @Werner: I will try to do that, but it's a little difficult given that there is a pretty large .sty file.

Comment: @user14269: That responsibility lies with you. Asking questions come without a charge... so that's the least you can do to make answers come your way more readily.

Comment: the image you posted is with or without `\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{-2.5em}Chapter}`?

Comment: @user14269: The **full** `.sty` would be much more helpful, as well as the document, with a dummy chapter, for example

Comment: Don't you need the "Page" on the second page of the table of contents too?

Comment: the problem may be the use of `\include`.  that always delays the application of any command (like `\addtocontents`) that will write something to another file.  just before the first `\include`, insert `\clearpage` (which would be applied anyway); that will force the write.

Comment: @touhami: \addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{-2.5em}Chapter} is commented out

Comment: @Barbarabeeton: I think you have something there. I will try your suggestion, after I have submitted my dissertation. Right now I solved the problem in a rather hacky manner, which I have detailed in my updated question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank God no! Having it on the first page is hard enough.

Comment: it is not hard. Normally I put the text in the header.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Shall we vote to close this as off-topic (since 'solved') or shall we wait until the O.P. updates (as he/she promised)?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I'm going to try to put it up Thursday night EST. I'll make a note of it. If that is too late, then please go ahead and close this. Or let me know if I need to do something to close it.

Comment: @user14269: I'll not vote for close then